# Is there a way to monitor changes like "nodemon" for Firebase command line?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, nodemon, firebase-polymer, firebase-tools

Is there any way to get the Firebase command line to simply refresh the server as I am applying changes to code similar to what nodemon does for nodeJS? I'm working with Polymer for web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently a feature of the Firebase CLI, but it sounds like something that would be useful. Please [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: The Firebase Hosting CLI actually monitors the source folder and reloads when there are changes. If there are changes under there, they should be picked up. If you're having problems getting that to work, I'd open a new question with the [minimal steps on how to reproduce that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 18):

adding to @grigson, you can also use the exec flag to run a package.json script eg:

```
nodemon -e ts --exec "npm run serve"
```

where *serve* is the command in your functions package.json (ie.

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
     ...
     "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
     ...
}
```

By running this, nodemon will also run **build** before **serve**. The -e flag tells nodemon to watch for changes in files with a .ts extension.

Answer (score 16):

I'm using nodemon with firebase cloud function, 
as *firebase-tools@3.17.4* (current)

`firebase serve --only functions` detects changes only in `index.js`

this can be handled with **nodemon** `--exec` flag

`nodemon --exec firebase serve --only functions`